# Laravel deny access by URL to the items in the database if it's don't belonged to the current user?

Tags: php, laravel, permissions

I have a database table where we store all products for all user.
We getting product page by product id number something like this `http://sitename.com/inventory/product/3`.

How can I deny access to the product by URL if this product doesn't belong to the current user?

Comment: You have a million options. Creating custom [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware) would be an easy, effective solution.

Answer (score 0):

The [Auth](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication) middleware can be used for this. In the function for the route you can do something like:

```
public function show($id){

  //get the user visiting the route
  $user = Auth::user();

  //get the product by the id in the url
  $product = Product::where('id','=',$id)->first();

  if($user->id == $product->user_id){

    //return the route like normal

  }else{

    //redirect or return route with different data

  }

}
```

Just make sure to add `use Auth;` to your controller. And you'll want to [protect your route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#protecting-routes) to ensure only authenticated users can access it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `firstOrFail()` in the controller? Assuming that your product record contains a `created_by` which refers to the owner id, you will search by both `id` and `created_by`. If nothing found, then a 404 exception will be thrown.

```php
public function show(Request $request){

    // Get the user-id
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    // Get the product matching by id and owned by the current user
    $product = Product::where('id', $request->id)->where('created_by',$user_id)->firstOrFail();

    // Do your magic here if product found

}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-single-models